# UITabBarController set action to specific tab

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I would like to set an action to specific `tab` on `UITabBarController`. How can I do this?
 See my code below:
**Update with code**

```
@interface AccountTabViewController : UIViewController <UITabBarControllerDelegate, UITabBarDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabController;
    IBOutlet UITabBar *tabBar;
}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if(tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0) 
    {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

It never get into the method! Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [UITabBarDelegate reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarDelegate) and [UITabBarControllerDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).
The method you are looking for is

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
}
```

or one of these:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
}

- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
}
```

Also, [UITabBarController reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: for some reason it's not getting into the method!

Comment: Make sure your definition has `<UITabBarControllerDelegate,UITabBarDelegate>` like so: `@interface iPhoneHomeViewController : UIViewController <UITabBarControllerDelegate,UITabBarDelegate> { }`.  And you have to set the delegate property of the `UITabBar / UITabBarController` to the class with the delegate methods.

Comment: Do you have `[tabController setDelegate:self];`?  Also, you can use this to dismiss the current ViewController from that ViewController: `[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: @HardCode, read carefully. You should set UITabBarController's delegate.

Comment: I have self.view = tabController.view; in viewDidLoad And where do I put [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];?

Comment: Put tabController.delegate = self; in 'viewDidLoad' or after you have init/alloc'd tabController.

Answer (score 4):

Look at UITabBarControllerDelegate method:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
   if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0) 
   {
     // First Tab is selected do something
   }
}
```